# iterate through ALL rows in a GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelected" runat="server" Checked="false"></asp:CheckBox>
  </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

elow code works fine but there is a bug :

if Employee object has return 5 rows and i am trying to checked the check box based on the ids but instead its just matching only the last id - it suppose to checked all 5 rows..

```
List<Employee> result = new List<Employee>();
long Id = (long)Session["Id"];
result = Employee.GetEmployeeById(Id);

foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
{
   CheckBox chkBox = row.FindControl("chkSelected") as CheckBox;
   if (c != null)
   {
      if (result.Count > 0)
      {
          foreach (Employee item in result)
          {
             Label Id = row.FindControl("lblId") as Label;
             if (Id.Text == item.Id.ToString())
             {
                 chkBox.Checked = true;
             }
             else
             {
                chkBox.Checked = false;
             }
           }
       }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at your logic - you only have the one checkbox.  You're unchecking and checking the same control in the employee loop.  Does each grid row have a checkbox that should be selected based on the condition the id exists in the employee list?

```
 foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
    {
        Label Id = row.FindControl("lblId") as Label;
        var result = Employee.GetEmployeeById(Id.Text);
        if (result.Count > 0)
        {
            CheckBox chkBox = row.FindControl("chkSelected") as CheckBox;
            if (chkBox != null)
            {
                chkBox.Checked = result.Any(x => x.Id.ToString() == Id.Text);

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: hmmm...ic now...  but how do i iterate to get checkbox in gridviewrow ?

Comment: i udated my question with html markup, answer to your question yes.

Comment: i am comparing two ids, one id from gridviewrow and the other id i am getting from employee object `foreach (Employee....` i am not sure your code will work.

Comment: you need to iterate each gridviewrow, find the checkbox, find the id, select if id exists in your employee list.  Is that correct?

Comment: yes, i am using `foreach gridviewrow` and inside the first foreach loop i am looping for employee object... thats the confusing part.

Comment: You're using variables with same names (i.e. 'Id') so the code needs refactoring - what I gave you should get you on your way.

Comment: when i debug i see that `chkBox.Checked = true` but its not checked on the gridview... is that the same i am checking and unchecking the same control??? ?

Comment: are you debugging code similar to what i posted or your original? And are you rebinding the gridview after this event (mistakenly)?